# Strategy for buying local leads from Adwords?

Tags: advertising

I want to use Adwords to get local leads to my web/app development service website. What are some things I should look out for?

Currently I'm thinking of starting with a tiny budget ($1 a day), maybe not enough to get leads because at most I will be getting 1 click a day at a cost of 0.05/click. So I would need more fine tuned keywords (how can I find a good keyword to find people searching for web development service in my city?)

What are some other tips and tricks to acquire leads from google?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are in a niche, $1 a day might be too little. Web development is definitely not a niche, so unless you offer a very specific service within web development you will get very little results with the current budget.

To find good keywords, define which keywords you would like people to search for when they find you or what you expect people to search for. Again, "web development Yourcity" will most likely be a very expensive set of keywords so you'll need to specify and diversify: do you have a specific type of customer in mind? Do you have a specialty?

Google offers some tools to analyze searches for finding keywords, most notably [Keyword Planner](https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner/Home).